# Court decides that Rob must pay Alice. Is she obliged to take the payment?

Tags: fines, crime, victims-rights

Reading [this article](https://www.stuff.co.nz/national/300715109/victim-rejects-200-payment-from-man-who-escaped-conviction-for-her-indecent-assault) where a crime victim rejected a $200 payment that the court had ordered the offender to pay her made me think: what happens now? Is she obliged to take it?

If she doesn't provide her bank account number, would the offender be entitled to find it out and make the payment anyway?

If he comes by and drops two $100 bills in front of her but yet she doesn't pick those up, would that be considered that he has paid?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: @NateEldredge Any you can answer about.

Answer (score 4):

Fines and reparation are [paid to the court](https://victimsupport.org.nz/practical-information/after-sentencing/reparations) not directly to victims/complainants:

> The offender pays the court and the court will send payment to [the recipient]

Comment: So, what happens if Alice doesn't provide her account details to the court? Can she be compelled to? Or will the court pocket the money?

Comment: I'm sure that the disposition of any undeliverable funds is going to be different based on the laws and/or policies of the city, county, or state where the court resides.

Comment: @jwh20 Sure it will be. The question is whether the court will _compel_ Alice to receive the funds or not. That said, can Alice stand her ground rejecting it?

Comment: @Greendrake it'll be kept in trust for some time and eventually taken by the government as abandoned

Comment: @Greendrake: I can't imagine anyone will be *compelled*.  Presumably the court sends Alice a letter saying "we have your funds, here is how to collect them".  If she never takes action to do so, she'll never get the money.

Comment: In my jurisdiction (England and Wales) court-ordered compensation is paid by the offender into the court. The court finance office then sends a cheque to the assigned payee. There can be problems of account reconciliation for major supermarket chains when they get cheques from e.g. convicted shoplifters or those who have caused criminal damage. One supermarket guy told me they 'didn't have a category' and processing the cheques was going to cost more than their value. Impecunious criminals can be made to pay small sums every month.